# Experiencing problems with lists

Tags: vb.net

I have a section of code where I add items to a list, as follows:

```
      If surname.Count < (noofcompetitors - 1) Then
             surname.Add(txtSurname.Text)
      Else
             This sequence ends (not actual code)
```

The value of `noofcompetitors` is 5, meaning I should have to enter 5 names and this partion of the code ends. However, I have to enter 6 names and when I run:

```
        For Each name As String In surname
            Console.WriteLine(name)
        Next
```

I get 5 names. Does anyone know how I can fix this so that I enter five names and 5 names are saved to the list? If you have any questions please ask.

Note: this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: What is in the else statement? That code will only appear on the 6th try, if you are printing the information in there, then it will only print when you try to add the 6th item. Put breakpoint and step trough the code.

Comment: The answer posted is correct: if there are 4 names in the list, then it will not add a 5th: 4 is not less than (5-1).  Thats what debuggers help find: logic errors

Answer (score 1):

Not really understand should there 5 or 6 of names, but I think you shouldn't minus 1 in `If surname.Count < (noofcompetitors - 1) Then`

Where the loop will be (assume noofcompetitors is 5):

```
surname.Count = 0 | noofcompetitors - 1 = 4 :: true
surname.Count = 1 | noofcompetitors - 1 = 4 :: true
surname.Count = 2 | noofcompetitors - 1 = 4 :: true
surname.Count = 3 | noofcompetitors - 1 = 4 :: true
surname.Count = 4 | noofcompetitors - 1 = 4 :: false
```

that causes your last data will never be added

Comment: The end result is 5 names which is correct, however I still have to enter 6 names

Comment: @MyArmsFellOff I don't think the block you posted is actual controlling how many names you have to enter, this block controlled how to add the entered data. According to my answer, it is an expected behavior that getting 5 names by 6 inputted names